# Check a user's custom status ( discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Had some issues with checking a user's custom status. When I did it, it would only show the status of the user and not their custom status.

```
@bot.command()
async def statuscheck(ctx):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member.status)
```

This return returned not the custom status but just the normal status. It would also only return for the bot. Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

`user.activities` returns the all activities of `user` and you want to get `discord.CustomActivity`.

```
for activity in user.activities:
  if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity): #checking activity is a custom activity
    print(activity)
```

Comment: got the error ```command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.user' has no attribute 'activities'```

Comment: i write in user but discord.User has no attribute activites. You can get activities only from member object. So can you try this on a guild member?

Comment: it returned the game they are playing, but I need their custom status

Comment: Can you share the code? I tried in my bot and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can we talk on discord? @Weylyn? Ham#8842